# Bash completion does not work in ZSH/Oh-My-ZSH because COMP_WORDS is not an array

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh, bash-completion

I'm writing a bash command line tool for which I want to enable bash completion using [completely](https://github.com/DannyBen/completely).

I have the following bash completion. After I `eval "$(./cli completion)"` (which outputs the below), completions work fine in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This bash completions script was generated by
# completely (https://github.com/dannyben/completely)
# Modifying it manually is not recommended
_cli_completions() {
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  local comp_line="${COMP_WORDS[*]:1}"

  case "$comp_line" in
    'completions'*) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--help -h" -- "$cur")) ;;
    'download'*) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--force --help -f -h" -- "$cur")) ;;
    ''*) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--help --version -h -v completions download" -- "$cur")) ;;
  esac
}

complete -F _cli_completions cli
```

However, they do not work right in ZSH. I have identified the problem to be that `COMP_WORDS` is not an array when I'm inside ZSH, but it is inside bash. This then breaks the line `local comp_line="${COMP_WORDS[*]:1}"`.

E.g. in the situation `./cli download <tab>`, `comp_line` should be `download`, but in ZSH it's `/cli download` (only the `.` is removed), so I always end up in the last case `''*`.

I'm using ZSH 5.8 with Oh-My-ZSH. Bash completions generally seem to work in ZSH.
Oh-My-ZSH sets up completions using

```
fpath=($ZSH/functions $ZSH/completions $fpath)
autoload -U compaudit compinit
```

I have tried setting `setopt shwordsplit`, hoping that that would cause `COMP_WORDS` to be treated as an array, but it had no effect.

Is there a ZSH configuration that I can change to make this completion script work?
Or is there a bash compatible change to the completion script that would make it work in both shells?

Comment: Certainly because Zsh is not Bash, so Bash specific auto-completion methods and variables are specific to Bash and not understood by Zsh. Hope someone with both Bash and Zsh knowledge can help you with equivalent features and implementations for Zsh auto-completion.

Comment: @Nicolas: You don't really expect a tool for one programming language (bash) magically work for a different languag, do you? What cou could do is to inspect the source code of the bash completion system as inspiration, re-implement it in zsh, and then do something good for this planet and release your solution as open source, so that all zsh users can benifit from it.

Comment: @user1934428 `zsh` provides `bashcompinit`, which claims to allow you to use `bash` completion scripts in `zsh`. It has (not well documented) limitations, though.

Comment: @chepner: Interesting to know. This means that the OP at least has to run _bashcompinit_, before fiddling with the bash completion system, and then can hope that it may work. Perhaps you could provide this as answer. I have the impression that _bashcompinit_ is a feature which is not that widely known, so your answer could be valuable for many zsh users.

Comment: I don't know enough about it to really push it as the answer to *this* question. Anecdotally, I tried it a while ago with a `bash` completion script that it couldn't handle. I don't use it myself, but mainly because the few custom completions I have in use are written specifically for `zsh`.

Comment: It's far better to write a native zsh completion. The result works much more nicely and it is no harder to implement. `bashcompinit` may work, just run `autoload -U bashcompinit; bashcompinit` and it is enabled but you need to deal with sh compatibility and lots of silly issues. Writing a zsh function is normally easier.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Thanks to oh-my-zsh, bash-style completion generally works on my system as is. I tried `bashcompinit` but that had no effect on the behavior I described

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is discussed in [this Github ticket](https://github.com/DannyBen/bashly/issues/168).

ZSH should be totally capable of handling bash completions when it is configured to do so by adding these two lines in `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
# Load bash completion functions
autoload -Uz +X compinit && compinit
autoload -Uz +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
```

In addition, the script in question, generated by the completely gem, seems to have a problem.

Replacing `*` with `@` in the below line seems to make it work on both bash and zsh.

```bash
local comp_line="${COMP_WORDS[*]:1}"   # broken
local comp_line="${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}"   # works
```

*This change is now a part of both bashly and completely gems.*